# Notify when a comment has been flagged

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, comment-flags

A flagging on a comment could mean "This comment mentioned a minor error in the post that has now been fixed" and is now only noise (especially if upvoted before). So it would be nice to be notified of that flag to delete the comment right away.

Comment: This would of course also be useful for questions/answers, but there a glance at downvotes is at least an indication, plus in that case it should be more obvious that one has produced something flag-"worthy"